# TFS - pull request creation does not notify default approve group

Tags: tfs, pull-request, email-notifications

We have TFS 2018 Update 3. We have git repositories and branches on them are secured with branch policies. 
We have TFS groups which are through branch policies used as default approve groups for pull requests.

**Problem:** when somebody creates a PR to a particular branch, we'd expect, that people in the default group receive an email from TFS that new PR was created.
Despite the fact, that all of them have their own notifications enabled, they do not receive it...

Is there any configuration I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the notification in the Team level:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering - let me test it. However, i do not have "All team members" drop down... And I'm not sure whether this will work for TFS groups we use as approve group.